# Writing variables to a hex file in Python

Tags: python, file, io, hex

So, I have got a float value: -1.0f, or something. And how could I write it into a file in hexadecimal format in Python? I mean that we open the file in notepad, we won't see the hexadecimal values, just the ASCII code.

Comment: What is the desired output? Hex or not hex? Some example?

Comment: Check out `struct.pack` and the built-in `ord` and `hex` functions.  Use them in series in that order.

Comment: [`float.hex()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#float.hex) may also be useful.

Comment: So, if I wasn't understandable, I explain one more time. The desired output is hex. With C++ I can solve the problem of byte order, so the output would be 3F800000. Any solutions, please?

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3:

```
>>> import struct
>>> "".join("{0:02X}".format(b) for b in struct.pack(">f", -1.0))
'BF800000'
```

In Python 2:

```
>>> import struct
>>> "".join("{0:02X}".format(ord(b)) for b in struct.pack(">f", -1.0))
'BF800000'
```

Comment: And what is "b" for? And does the ">f" mean the filename?